# Do NSArrays stay sorted when saved then retrieved from a plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Simple question do NSArrays stay sorted when saved to a plist and then retrieved?

I am having a sorting issue when i retrieve my array from my plist so i was curious.

I think it may also be a problem with this line. Do these maintain the order from titles followed the order of titleArr?

```
NSMutableArray *allTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[allTitles addObjectsFromArray:titles];
[allTitles addObjectsFromArray:titleArr];
```

How I save to plist

```
imageInfo = [[NSMutableArray array] init];

    NSMutableArray *Listing = [NSMutableArray array];
    [imageInfo addObject:Listing];

    NSDictionary *Images = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            allTitles, kKeyTitle,
                            allMediaUrls, kKeyThumbUrl,
                            allWidths, kKeyThumbWidth,
                            allHeights, kKeyThumbHeight,
                            nil];
    [Listing addObject:Images];


    NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.plist"];

    NSLog(@"Plist File Path: %@", filePath);

    BOOL didWriteToFile = [imageInfo writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    if (didWriteToFile) {
        NSLog(@"Write to .plist file is a SUCCESS!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Write to .plist file is a FAILURE!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if `titles` and `titleArr` are sorted than `allTitles`  will also be sorted.

First all objects of titles will be added and than at all objects `titleArr` will be added as `addObjectsFromArray` method starts adding object array towards the end of receiving array.

Here is more info from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Adds the objects contained in another given array to the end of the
>   receiving array’s content.

So yes `plist`  will have sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

Severe bug:

```
imageInfo = [[NSMutableArray array] init];
```

[NSMutableArray array] returns an initialised and autoreleased array. 
Sending an init message to that array is not a good idea.

Comment: This is how I've always been setting up my mutable arrays, is it that dire of a situation?

Comment: is there a better way to initialize it/ empty it?